# Is this a Bad Programming Practice in Android?

Tags: android, formatting, coding-style

in java i know this code is a good programming practice,
but i read some article there are good programming practice that
is bad for Android, i just want to know if this type of code
can affect the Aplication Performance issue when it comes to android programing?

for example

```
public class Main {

    static int age = getAge(10); /***************** THIS LINE */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(age);
    }

    private static int getAge(int i) { /***************** THIS METHOD */
        i = i + 1;

        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What could be bad with it? Apart from the fact that you could just simply `i++` instead of sending it a method

Comment: if you mean calling methods within android, it is totally fine and actually it is desirable.

Comment: You need a better example. What you've shown here is just pointless.  Which part *exactly* are you questioning?

Comment: If you are talking about static variable inside an `Activity`, then it is somewhat dangerous as the variable is not always available (e.g if the activity/app is force-killed by the OS). Otherwise, if it is inside other class, then there should be no problem.

Comment: ahh thanks for the info i thought there are other java coding style that will affect the android coding when it come to speed performance issue, thanks to all!

Comment: Hi Piolo, would you like to accept an answer for the question if you're satisfied, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This situation seems perfectly fine and wouldn't effect performance.

I personally would be careful with this practice though, you could potentially call a method dependant on variables that are yet to be initialized.

```
public class Main {

   static int age = getDogYears(10);
   int dogRatio; // dogRatio is not yet initialized

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(age);            

        dogRatio = 7;
    }

    private static int getDogyears(int i) { 
        i = i * dogRatio; // null pointer exception because dogRatio is not initialized

        return i;
    }
}
```

If the problem is really this simple though I would also ask why you wouldn't just make age = 11;

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to see any noticeable performance hits, and I can't see anything *wrong* with the code, but it could be improved.

This method is a lot easier to read and cleans up the code a little:

```
private static int getAge(int i){
    return i++;
}
```

You also then have to wonder why you even need it. As you're passing it an integer and not the value of a variable, why not just initialise it without the method call?

```
static int age = 11;
```

Comment: ahh i understand now, when using android if the code will be done with simplier aproach so il use the more easy and more less use of ann object to improve performance issue. So simplier is the better right?

Comment: You should always make the code as simple as is possible, without sacrificing functionality or performance (to the point where it matters). In your particular example there is no requirement at all for the use of the method and removing it makes the code much easier to understand.